# Is there any reason to lock a queue?

Tags: multithreading, queue, locking

I'm just wondering if there would be any reason I might want to lock a queue. I am working on an application that has several threads that reads and writes to a database. In order to reduce traffic, I want to reduce the amount of calls to that database at any given point (I know many databases can handle some traffic already). Would it make any sense to make a queue for the read/write requests and only the request at the top executes and then protect the queue's push and pop commands with a lock? Is having a lock on each read/write call enough? Isn't a lock implemented as a "queue" by the OS anyways? Could size of this "queue" be an issue or would there be any other reason I wouldn't use a lock by itself?
Thanks!

Comment: This question is too broad: much depends on the architecture, how many request per seconds you're supposed to support, what's the expected latency, what's the SLA etc. Further, in Java we have `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` which can be used. Other languages might have similar offering (via libraries/frameworks). It's also not clear why do you want to lock on reads.

Comment: I am using Python, Linux OS on a raspberry pi 3 connecting to the Google cloud datastore, I don't have a definite number for requests per second its supposed to support, but potentially 25 or so connections could come in at the same time. Wouldn't I want to lock on reads to ensure consistency of the data? Would @jspcal suggestion to use a semaphore to limit conncurent operations be sufficient?

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. I am running a python script that will be running on top of Linux OS on a raspberry pi 3. The python script takes external data and makes database read/writes to the Google Cloud Datastore.

Comment: In a single process, the built-in`Semaphore` is exactly what you need: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.BoundedSemaphore

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. Do you happen to know if I would want to use the semaphore with reads to the database as well or is that overkill?

Comment: The threads for my purpose also serve to service TCP connections to the exterior environment so I wouldn't want to limit that. I'll give the semaphore a go, thank you.

Comment: @Joe121212: Do not explain the question in the *comments*. Instead, add required information into the **question post** itself (by [edit]ing it).

Comment: If you're using Python you shouldn't be using threads at all. For more info read about [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock).

Answer (score 0):

You could limit the number of threads that are engaged in database requests or if that's not feasible due to the nature of your app, you could use a more granular approach to limit access to the shared resource. In python, you can use the built-in [semaphore objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.BoundedSemaphore) for inter-thread synchronization. For inter-process synchronization (or inter-thread), you'd use [posix_ipc](http://semanchuk.com/philip/posix_ipc/). It depends what your service's execution model is.

Most database clients wouldn't require any application-level throttling. In a typical system, the database connections would be pooled and the connection manager would be responsible for acquiring an available connection. Internally this usually involves a queue of some sort with timeouts to prevent waiting indefinitely. The database itself would then handle the scheduling of individual operations made by each connection.

However, a semaphore is a signalling primitive that can be used to limit the number of concurrent operations: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html

Tasks can also be modeled as a [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) which involves a shared queue, however you'll have to deal with the added complexity of managing the consumer threads in addition to the producers.